# Custom operating system on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: operating-systems, software-development, java

Me and a fellow coder friend are looking to create our own [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (OS). We're looking to create a Java-based OS, so I would love to poke about the [JNode OS](http://www.jnode.org/) for inspiration.

Is there a way to run JNode, and our own OS, on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Please add what you found out (with link) about running VMWare on the RaPi.

Comment: You wouldn't have to make it PD, but I imagine they also won't like disclosing the source under license.

Comment: @xtl We live in a world where we think that it is worth more to me if you don't have it. So Kezz101 has to ask permission.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure about Jnode, but the Computer Laboratory at Cambridge University has a short course on OS development on the Raspberry Pi that you might be interested in:

[Baking Pi - Operating Systems Development](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/freshers/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/)

Comment: Thank you! I found that article very interesting... It'll certainly help in the long run!

Answer (score 3):

You are in for a lot of pain if you go the Java way.  Also operating systems capable of actually *doing* anything interesting takes much more work than you most likely think.

JNode requires as of now more memory than the Pi has and is not ported to the Raspberry, so it will require quite a bit of elbow grease to get up and running.

You might find it much more rewarding in terms of actually getting the computer to *do* something, to do some work on completing driver support on the Linux distribution you end up using.  Raspbian seems to be where the momentum are these days.

Comment: Ah thanks for the advice! I did indeed go down the path of modifying the Raspian distro to support Java to run a sort of 'embedded OS'.

Comment: Note that since I wrote the answer, Oracle has come out with a JVM suitable for the Raspberry.

Comment: Is this the JDK8 prerelease? If so, might it be worth updating this comment?